# Can the null vector $\vec{0}$ be equated to zero scalar $0$?

Tags: vectors

I found a question stating when is the cross product of two vectors A and B equal to their dot product. Wondering how a scalar can be equated to a vector.

Comment: Found where? Which page?

Comment: I guess it implies _the magnitude_ of the cross product equals the dot product.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are talking about the *magnitude* of the cross product, the answer would be never. There is no accepted way to compare a scalar to a vector. If the question is asking about the magnitude of the cross product, then we just would solve

$$|A||B|\cos \theta = |A||B|\sin \theta,$$

so the answer would be when $\theta = 45^\circ$ or when $|A|=0$ or $|B| = 0$.

Comment: ... or when $|A|=0$ or $|B|=0$.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect that.